# Enabling Manual Garbage Collection in Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I have been trying to get Garbage Collection and Max Old Space Size configured in our compiled and built Electron app.

I am able to debug with these settings on through the CLI `electron.cmd --js-flags="--expose_gc --max-old-space-size=128" .` and the Global GC is available.

However when I try and use the electron API `app.commandLine.appendArgument('--js-flags', '--expose_gc --max-old-space-size=128');` to set these flags it doesn't enable GC as expected, this code is being called before the `app.on('ready', ...)` function.

Nor does setting NODE_OPTIONS help (I see that this has been disabled in the latest Electron version as per here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12695)

Does anyone have experience getting this working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('js-flags', '--expose_gc --max-old-space-size=128')
```

The first argument of appendSwitch does not use the `--` prefix, just drop that. The seconds argument is parsed as is, thats why it keeps the prefix.

Also be aware it only exposes gc for the renderer if you use apppendSwitch, if you want to use it there you will need to add the CLI argument.

Comment: Thanks, now that I see it that was super obvious.

I will see if I can submit a pull request on the [command line docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md) to highlight this. 

As for getting the GC to work in the Main Process I found this to work:

`require("v8").setFlagsFromString('--expose_gc');`
`global.gc = require("vm").runInNewContext('gc');`

Thanks again. :)